# Force browser to open CSVs in-browser rather than downloading?

Tags: csv, browser

I'm asking this from the perspective of a browser user, rather than as a developer:

I would like my browser to display CSV files in-browser rather than downloading the file to my machine. I do not have access to the sites I'd like to do this for. Is there a way to do this (in any major browser--Chrome, Firefox, etc.)?

It this question is better suited for Super User or elsewhere, just let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not currently know any non-extension way for this especially since you have no access to the server-side but you could use a browser extension for this:

Chrome: [Undisposition](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/undisposition-racle-fork/bbppejejjfancffmhncgkhjdaikdgagc?hl=en)

Firefox: [InlineDisposition](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/inlinedisposition-reloaded/)